# How can I render a texture in a specific x/y position on the screen? (OpenGL - glium)

Tags: opengl, game-loop, rust

I am in the process of writing a 2D game in Rust, and decided to use `glium` for the graphics part. So far I'm doing fine, able to render textures and shapes perfectly.

Now comes the most important part where I get the mouse coordinates, and then whenever I click, a texture will be placed under the mouse cursor. I've implemented the first two parts of listening on mouse movement and mouse down events, so now I have to load the texture and pass it's position on the vertex buffer.

From my understanding, I have to convert my mouse's X and Y from window coordinates to OpenGL coordinates (-1, 1), then pass those to the vertex buffer. This still doesn't make any sense on my head though.

(You can reply even if you do not know about glium; I know how to implement raw OpenGL calls to glium calls).

Comment: Sounds like you need to work with Orthographic Camera and Viewport in matching dimensions (e.g. 1920x1080). Conversion to -1,1 is usually done last and is out of scope of your apps main flow. It might be better to go over a tutorial to get up to speed with OpenGL (e.g. https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll see what glium offers for those terms as I really never worked with matrices myself.